# Bitbucket Scriptrunner script Post hook does not trigger on pull-request merge

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am using bit-bucket script runner plugin recently. within Script post hooks I have added a custom script to trigger, the trigger happens for commit push but it does not trigger the script upon pull-request merge.

Any help from people who have used script runner script post hooks on pull request merge will be helpful.

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use "**Script Event Handlers**" or "**Listener**" and trigger your script on the "**PullRequestMergedEvent**" event.

you can access event in your script:

```
def bugId = event.getPullRequest().fromRef.getDisplayId()
```